# How to grab Fibonnacci levels' price to perform calculations?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Based on TradingView's built-in [Auto Fib Retracement](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000585089)  code, how to calculate and plot the price difference between 0 and 1.
I cannot figure out how and where to grab the price value of these Fibonnacci levels in the pinescript code.

[Example from the linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kpsf.png) : I'd like the indicator to minus 6737,7 (level 0) to 6710,2 (level 1) which gives 27,5.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way :

```
price_0 = line.get_price(lineId4, bar_index)
price_1 = line.get_price(lineId11, bar_index)
amplitude = price_0 - price_1
```

`lineId#` is one of Auto Fib Retracement level.

I'm not expert in Pinescript so there may be better ways.